# Heroku application error node.js app, when deploying

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    apiOptions.server = "https://pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com";
```

and my verison of npm and node are the same as specified on the packge.json.

I can't figure out the problem.

I tried heroku restart, heroku ps:scale web=0 and heroku ps:scale web=1,set the JWT_SECRET on heroku.
nothing is working

any ideas?? am I missing something?

```
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.224489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.224809+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.224892+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls bookFace
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.224976+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.228404+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.228253+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.228474+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.291775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2017-03-29T23:34:56.325835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2017-03-29T23:35:00.496063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com request_id=53f989a3-f47c-48c2-8c79-1234136b53f6 fwd="80.1.102.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2017-03-29T23:35:01.865707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com request_id=e9f50e76-4c05-4b81-88d8-1be6026a2715 fwd="80.1.102.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered strange crashes while using `heroku & node.js` and one of them had to do with me accidentally uploading `node_modules` directory from my local machine. In my case it caused conflicts while heroku was trying to install dependencies.

See if that is the case. If that does not help than please provide more context to your question.